# How to prevent width of child element resize when scroll bar visible?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I am creating a menu with scrollbar which it will be visibled when items in menu overflow out of vertical. But when scrollbar is visibled, the items inside will resize width.

When scrollbar invisible:

[image: Scrollbar invisible]

When scrollbar visible:

[image: Scrollbar visible]

Here is my code on Tailwind Playground: https://play.tailwindcss.com/IhZSluWfIy

I need to keep width of item menu like inherit. How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

Add `style="scrollbar-gutter: stable;"` to the parent div:

https://play.tailwindcss.com/zGT2EBpznK

Comment: to add, my tailwind env required the following: `style={{ scrollbarGutter: "stable" }}`